# Overloading a std::function parameter in templated method in templated class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

I have trouble making a specialized template for a templated method in a class template specialization.

Let's say I have the following code:

```
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
class myClass {
public:
    T bar() {
        return T();
    }

    template<typename P>
    bool foo(std::function<P(T)> g) {
        g(bar());
        return true;
    }
};
```

If I wanted to specialize the function `bar` for `myClass<void>` I would do it this way:

```
template<> void myClass<void>::bar() {

}
```

But when I tried to specialize `foo` in the same way, i get a compiler error saying `error: invalid parameter type ‘void’` and pointing at the original definition of foo.

```
template<>
template<typename P>
bool myClass<void>::foo(std::function<P(void)> g) {
    bar();
    g();
    return true;
}
```

Does anybody have any advice, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to use `std::function<P()>` instead of `std::function<P(void)` ?

Comment: I did, the error stayed the same.

Comment: That last part looks like a partial specialization of function template (and with missing template arguments) which is prohibited. `foo` specialization should look like `template<> template<> bool myClass<void>::foo< void >(std::function< void (void)> g)`. Or you should've wrote it inside of `myClass` template specialization because that template class specialization will need new `foo` template function, you can not just specialize `foo` from base template like it is in specialized template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly specialization... you can use SFINAE (`std::enable_if`) to activate your version of `foo()` when `T` isn't `void` and activate another version of `foo()` when `T` is `void`.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
class myClass
 {
   public:
      T bar()
       { return {}; }

      template <typename P, typename U = T>
      typename std::enable_if<false == std::is_same<U, void>::value,
               bool>::type foo (std::function<P(U)> const & g)
       { g(bar()); return true; }

      template <typename P, typename U = T>
      typename std::enable_if<true == std::is_same<U, void>::value,
               bool>::type foo (std::function<P()> const & g)
       { bar(); g(); return false; }
 };

template<>
void myClass<void>::bar ()
 { }

int main()
 {
   myClass<int>   mci;
   myClass<void>  mcv;

   std::function<long(int)> fli { [](int i){ return long(i); } };
   std::function<short()>   fsv { [](){ return 0; } };

   std::cout << mci.foo(fli) << std::endl; // print 1
   std::cout << mcv.foo(fsv) << std::endl; // print 0
 }
```

Comment: That solved the problem, but didn't answer the question.